# Disable default mobile menu view in Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I've purchased and installed a premium wordpress theme, it's a very beautiful theme but the navigation menu in mobile view in very simple and unattractive, i tried changing the css code, installing the 'wp-responsive-menu' plugin, but the default view is not changing at all..
please help me..

click the link below for demo of the theme..

http://themes.themegoods2.com/kakia/

Please help me..

Comment: Do you want to remove the menu or restyle it?

Comment: Contact the theme developers.

Comment: I want to hide that menu and display the menu from the 'wp-responsive-menu' plugin..

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector for the menu is `#menu_border_wrapper select`.

If you wish to hide that menu:

```
#menu_border_wrapper select{
  display:none;
}
```

If you're looking to rebuild the menu then look at the [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function within WordPress, or contact the theme developers.